# How do I evenly add space between a label and the input field regardless of length of text?

Tags: forms, css, html

Let's say I have 10 input fields and before the input fields on the left side I have span tag that holds the text to indicate what the user should enter into the field.  I did some stuff but I am unsure how to add space in between the span tag and the input field regardless of how big the text is?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Here's some sample on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qAhQf/

Comment: First of all, use `label` instead of `span`. It's meant to be paired with inputs and preserves some additional functionality (clicking label focuses the input). Anyway. What exactly do you mean by "how to add stuff between the span tag and the input"? What kind of stuff? Do you mean you want all the labels to have the same width regardless of the contents?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect word, I meant even space.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## 2019 answer:

Some time has passed and I changed my approach now when building forms. I've done thousands of them till today and got really tired of typing id for every `label/input` pair, so this was flushed down the toilet. When you dive `input` right into the `label`, things work the same way, no ids necessary. I also took advantage of `flexbox` being, well, very flexible.

HTML:

```
<label>
  Short label <input type="text" name="dummy1" />
</label>

<label>
  Somehow longer label <input type="text" name="dummy2" />
</label>

<label>
  Very long label for testing purposes <input type="text" name="dummy3" />
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  height: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vb6Ln9ko/)

---

## Original answer:

Use `label` instead of `span`. It's meant to be paired with inputs and preserves some additional functionality (clicking label focuses the input).

This might be exactly what you want:

HTML:

```
<label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
<input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">

<label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
<input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">

<label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
<input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
```

CSS:

```
label {
    width:180px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}

input, label {
    float:left;
}
```

[jsfiddle DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qAhQf/1/)

Comment: Thanks.  In your example you have label for value equal to the value in the name and value attribute.  I am a bit new so I wanted to know what is the value that should be in label for? The value in the name field or value field? Or can it be anything?

Comment: Any tag attribute/contents could be whatever you want. Only thing that has to match is label's `for` attribute and input's `id` attribute to get the form logic done. `name` and `id` of each input doesn't have to be the same but it's a recommended good practice to avoid further confusion when reviewing your form. Hope it helps :)

Comment: It's also for accessibility reasons, that way the label is associated with that input, and you can click on the label to `focus` the input.

Comment: Thanks I am having issues aligning the select drop down with the label.

Comment: @starbucks Update your question then so I can update my answer. Right now according to your question everything has been solved.

Answer (score 16):

This can be accomplished using the brand new CSS `display: grid` ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid))

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
  <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
  <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
  <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
  <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
  <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
```

When using css grid, by default elements are laid out column by column then row by row. The `grid-template-columns` rule creates two grid columns, one which takes up 1/4 of the total horizontal space and the other which takes up 3/4 of the horizontal space. This creates the desired effect.

[image: grid]

[**JS-FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ufquL8p/)

Comment: The best solution.

Comment: Semi-related: how do you have that work when the label/inputs are nested (removing need for `for=`)?

Comment: It works as long as you use only text. `<label>"Text"<input/></label>`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a table

```
<table class="formcontrols" >   
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="firstName">FirstName:</label>
        </td>
        <td  style="padding-left:10px;">
            <input id="firstName" name="firstName" value="John">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Test">Last name:</label>
        </td>
        <td  style="padding-left:10px;">
            <input id="lastName" name="lastName" value="Travolta">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result would be:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also used below code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .labelClass{
            float: left;
            width: 113px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="yourclassName.jsp">
    <span class="labelClass">First name: </span><input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    <span class="labelClass">Last name: </span><input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `<span>` for the label, the semantically correct way is to use the `<label>` tag with a valid `for=""` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```css
label{
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always use the 'pre' tag inside the label, and just enter the blank spaces in it, So you can always add the same or different number of spaces you require

```
<form>
<label>First Name :<pre>Here just enter number of spaces you want to use(I mean using spacebar to enter blank spaces)</pre>
<input type="text"></label>
<label>Last Name :<pre>Now Enter enter number of spaces to match above number of 
spaces</pre>
<input type="text"></label>
</form>
```

Hope you like my answer, It's a simple and efficient hack