# php - formatting a link correctly

Tags: php, html

I have a question about an optical problem I have with php. I'm echoing a filename with this function:

`echo $name."<a href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>";`

The download link appears directly behind the file name like this `test.txtDownload`. How do I add spaces there or how is it possible to put the download link into the 'next column' so there are listed correctly among themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can play around this:

```
<?php echo $name."<a class='link' href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>";

 ?>
```

style:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     a.link {
        margin-left: 10px;
     }
 </style>
```

or simply :

```
<?php echo $name." <a class='link' href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>"; ?>
```

But I would suggest you to use `css` so that it can be managed, while normal space will not.

Comment: How would I set it up that the "download" would be listed among themselves not refering to the title lenght?

Comment: then you should go for bootstrap classes if using or other css trick, like this on :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275707/how-do-i-evenly-add-space-between-a-label-and-the-input-field-regardless-of-leng

Answer (score 0):

Just add a blank space in your string:

```
echo $name." <a href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>";
```

Another option would be use some css to set the appropriate space between link name and button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $name."  "."<a href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code. Download link appears in down

```
echo $name.<br>.<a href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>
```

instead of adding space use `&nbsp` instead of `<br>` tag.It will give you one tab space.